# Skins for VLC Media Player don't work in Lubuntu 14.04

Tags: lubuntu, vlc

I have installed VLC Media Player in a fresh install of Lubuntu 14.04 LTS Trusty Tahr, meaning that my installation uses the new Linux kernel 3.13. I have installed VLC Media Player using Synaptic, which uses the official Ubuntu repositories. VLC Media Player works fine, until I attempt to use a skin. I go into VLC Media Player's settings and choose the skin file like I am supposed to. I restart VLC Media Player, but something interesting happens. It shows in the taskbar as if it is opening, but the GUI doesn't load. Then within one second, VLC Media Player disappears from the taskbar, as if it closed itself or crashed. Sometimes when this happens, I get a window that says "Lubuntu 14.04 has experienced an internal error." Then it asks me to send the bug report, which I usually do, but that doesn't have anything to do with VLC Media Player. My question is: What is wrong? Is this a bug? Have I done something wrong? (I don't think so though, because I had no problem using skins in Lubuntu 13.10 Saucy Salamander.) What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Resolved by sefaustun in this post http://askubuntu.com/a/453991

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My wife had a similar problem after upgrading Lubuntu to 14.04 on her laptop. Under Lubuntu 13.10, she had *all* the skins (available for download from VLC's website) to choose from and changed skins frequently. I have no idea which skin was being used when Lubuntu was upgraded, but interestingly, the VLC icon that flashed on LXPanel for a moment was the "santa-hatted" one from Christmas. Subsequent times my wife tried again to start VLC from a desktop shortcut (5 different shortcuts to playlists we'd set up for her months ago) and got nothing. VLC wouldn't start.

There is probably a faster or easier solution for this/these problem(s); but the following is what I did to fix VLC back up to the way it was for her before:

1. To work with the files as root (as PCManFM no longer includes the option in a drop-down), go to *Menu --> Accessories --> LXTerminal* (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and type: `gksu pcmanfm`
2. Provide your password, then go to *View --> Show Hidden* (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>)
   Double-click the `.config` folder, select (single-click) the `vlc` folder inside, hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and confirm (<kbd>Enter</kbd> or click the "Yes" button) you want to permanently delete the vlc folder.
3. Click the back icon "<" and double-click the `.local` folder, then double-click the `share` folder inside and select (single-click) the `vlc` folder inside, hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. View files (change from Places) as Directory Tree, navigate to `/usr/share`, select (single-click) that `vlc` folder, hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd>
5. "X" out of PCManFM and back in LXTerminal, type: `sudo apt-get remove vlc`
6. Leave everything else it suggests that you also remove and just remove the one vlc package. As soon as it is done removing VLC, type: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install vlc`
7. "X" out of LXTerminal and go to (your default) Web Browser, type in http://www.videolan.org/vlc/skins.php and click the "here" hyperlink where you see "Download all the skins at once here (37MiB)."
8. Click the radio button to Save File and <kbd>Enter</kbd> (or click the "Okay" button).
9. Go to File Manager (PCManFM), double-click the Downloads folder, right-click (<kbd>F12</kbd>) `vlc-skins.zip` and choose "Extract Here" from the drop-down menu. Scroll down to find the (probably still-selected) <kbd>vlc-skins.zip</kbd> file and hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> to delete it.
10. Click one of the skins, then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to select all, right-click (<kbd>F12</kbd>) one of them and choose "Cut" from the drop-down menu.
11. Click the back icon "<" and double-click the `.local` folder, double-click the share folder inside and double-click the `vlc` folder in that. Right-click (<kbd>F12</kbd>) in an empty space, choose "Create New... --> Folder" and name it `skins2`
12. Double-click to enter the `skins2` folder you just made, right-click (<kbd>F12</kbd>) an empty space and choose "Paste" from the drop-down menu.
13. Right-click (<kbd>F12</kbd>) one of the skins and choose "Copy Path(s)" from the drop-down menu.
14. Go to *Menu --> Sound & Video --> VLC media player*
15. Go to Tools --> Preferences (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>) and under *Interface Settings, Look & Feel*; select the radio button for "Use custom skin."
16. Click in the "Skin resource file" text box and right-click (<kbd>F12</kbd>) or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste. <kbd>Enter</kbd>, or click the "Save" button.
17. Go to *Media --> Quit* (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd>). Go back to *Menu --> Sound & Video --> VLC media player*

The skin you copied the path to should be on VLC now (and changeable) and whatever files, playlists and/or shortcuts you had set up before to work with VLC should work again as well.